# Hadoop - datanode not running in slave

Tags: hadoop

Im trying to setup a cluster hadoop environment but unable to start the data node in the slave.

Here is my logs from the master node -

```
hduser@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ bash start-dfs.sh15/12/29 20:04:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: namenode running as process 5633. Stop it first.
slave: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-vagrant.out
master: datanode running as process 3362. Stop it first.
localhost: datanode running as process 3362. Stop it first.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 3527. Stop it first.
15/12/29 20:04:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
hduser@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ 
hduser@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
3527 SecondaryNameNode
3362 DataNode
5633 NameNode
6765 Jps
```

From the logs above it looks like it started but here is the slave node jps command -

```
hduser@vagrant:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ jps
3135 Jps
```

Don't see the datanode running.

Comment: Can you execute this command in the slave machine /usr/local/hadoop/bin hdfs datanode and post the output

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not put your slave address in /etc/hosts. Check it out. If It is OK, check the slave's logs then.